# Using ARGV to get user input in Awk script

Tags: text-processing, awk, input

I know `ARGV[i]` can be used for storing user input. However, I want to use it in awk script and get the `ARGV[i]` to compare the field from another text file. If the `ARGV[i]` matches the field or the field contains `ARGV[i]` which is the user input, then I want to return the other fields of that line.

Let say I have a file, `testing.txt`:

```
123123123:Walter White:1:2:3:4
123123124:Jesse Pinkman:1:3:4:1
```

This is my awk script, `awkScript.awk`:

```
 #!/usr/bin/awk -f
    BEGIN{FS = ":"; print "ENTER A NAME: "}
    {
        for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++)
        {   
            if ($2 ~ /'ARGV[i]'/)
            {
                print "Member ID: " $1
            }
        }
    }
```

It just prints ENTER A NAME: when I execute the script file. It doesn't even get the input from the user.

Comment: how do you call awk's file ? how do you tell awk to read `testing.txt` ? how do you think awk will get user input ?

Comment: awk -f awkScript.awk testing.txt
My question is how to get user input by using awk...

Comment: "ARGV[i] can be used for storing user input"  it's not user input, it's argument passing to awk script, like positional params to bash

Comment: Crossposted on SO...

Answer (score 3):

To match the contents of `ARGV[i]` you need to change your test to

`if ($2 ~ ARGV[i])`

Otherwise, you are testing for a match to the literal regex `'ARGV[i]'` which is not what you want.

Then your script will (kind of) work if you run it like this:

`awk -f qtest.awk testing.txt "Jesse Pinkman" "Walter White"`

But then it will throw an error when it finishes reading testing.txt and tries to open the file "Jesse Pinkman" (unless, of course, you happen to have a file with that name).

In other words, ARGV contains the *file names* passed to your script by the shell and you shouldn't try to use it for passing in arbitrary arguments. The usual way to pass non-file arguments to an awk script is to use the `-v var = val` syntax to initialise variables in your script.

But I suspect that a better approach here is to read testing.txt in your BEGIN block, using the `getline var <namefile.txt` syntax, splitting the data (using the `split()` function), and storing the split data in a 2D array. Then your main processing loop can read in names (either from a file or from the user) and you can then test those names using the data you've saved in the array.